# Installation of force.com IDE

Tags: salesforce

While installing force.com IDE software into eclipse I'm getting following error. Can anyone please help me to resolve this error?

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.salesforce.ide,29.0.0.201310181333.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 2077dcd58a86278b97c02fda56a61fb7 and found c0f025ffecb6211e4b9242fbac71cc2f.
Artifact not found: http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/plugins/com.salesforce.ide.deployment_29.0.0.201310181333.jar.
http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/plugins/com.salesforce.ide.deployment_29.0.0.201310181333.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Force.com IDE plugin officialy supports Eclipse version 3.6/3.5/3.4 and works under java 1.6
More higher eclipse version or java 1.7 may be the cause of your problem.
There are many workarounds in the Internet, please try to find them with google. 
Or you can try to use MavensMate

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the Force.com IDE can be installed to the latest version of Eclipse - **4.3 Kepler** - without any problems. Find detailed information [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation).

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with **Kepler** using following update site:

http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42